# Could not write request: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for request type with Feign

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-feign, feign

I want to implement request using Spring Cloud Feign client. I tried this:

***Feign client:***

```
@FeignClient(name = "mail-service", url = "mail-service")
public interface EmailClient {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/register")
    void setUserRegistration(RegisterUserDTO registerUserDTO);

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/password_reset")
    void setUserPasswordReset(PasswordResetDTO passwordResetDTO);
}
```

***Request DTO:***

```
public class RegisterUserDTO {
    private int id;

    public RegisterUserDTO() {
    }
}
```

***Controller:***

```
@Autowire
EmailClient emailClient;

@PostMapping("/dummy")
public ResponseEntity<?> test() {

    RegisterUserDTO obj = new RegisterUserDTO();

    emailClient.setUserRegistration(obj);

    return ok().build();
}
```

Feign configuration:

```
feign:
    client:
        config:
            default:
                connectTimeout: 5000
                readTimeout: 5000
                loggerLevel: basic
eureka:
    client:
        serviceUrl:
            defaultZone: ${EUREKA_URI:http://localhost:8761/eureka}
    instance:
        preferIpAddress: true
```

But when I make a POST request I get exception:

```
22:50:05.325 [http-nio-8090-exec-1] DEBUG DispatcherServlet[logResult:1101] - Failed to complete request: feign.codec.EncodeException: Could not write request: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for request type [org.engine.plugin.dto.RegisterUserDTO]
22:50:05.328 [http-nio-8090-exec-1] DEBUG HstsHeaderWriter[writeHeaders:169] - Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match the requestMatcher org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter$SecureRequestMatcher@461d6969
22:50:05.329 [http-nio-8090-exec-1] DEBUG SecurityContextPersistenceFilter[doFilter:119] - SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
22:50:05.334 [http-nio-8090-exec-1] ERROR [dispatcherServlet][log:175] - Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [/engine] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is feign.codec.EncodeException: Could not write request: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for request type [org.engine.plugin.dto.RegisterUserDTO]] with root cause
feign.codec.EncodeException: Could not write request: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for request type [org.engine.plugin.dto.RegisterUserDTO]
```

Do you know how I can solve this issue?

Comment: Try adding getters and setters to your POJO RegisterUserDTO.

Comment: I added getter/setter but still I get the same error.

Comment: That was the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I was using `openfeign` dependency without `spring-boot-starter-web`. After adding this dependency the error disappears. Probably because it contains the json mapper needed.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you have not added getter methods in your DTOs.

```
public class RegisterUserDTO {
    

    private int id;
    public RegisterUserDTO() {
    }
    public int getId() {
     return id;
    }


}
```

See the CODE which I have added.